# Default behavior of @Transactional annotation

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

When we write @Transactional on a method which behavior type is triggered automatically? and how it is different from other behaviors.

Behaviour type like propagation, isolation, rollback, timeout or readOnly

Comment: What do you mean by behavoir type?

Comment: Behaviour type like propagation, isolation, rollback, timeout or readOnly

Answer (score 0):

The default propagation is REQUIRED:

> Default:
>   org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation.REQUIRED

Isolation:

> Defaults to Isolation.DEFAULT.

And all the information can be found in the API Doc:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html

Also find more about transaction management in the official documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction-declarative